# How to implement Collapsabletoolbar with ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to implement Collapsabletoolbar, here is my code.

Main.xml

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"

            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/hgj_nav"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"

                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#009688"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In java:

```
public class MainActivityTab extends AppCompatActivity {

// Declaring Your View and Variables


Toolbar toolbar;
CharSequence HGJTitles[]={"Recent News","Category"};
int HGJNumboftabs =2;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

private AdView mAdView;
private StartAppAd startAppAd = new StartAppAd(this);
private InterstitialAd interstitial;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StartAppAd.init(this, getString(R.string.startapp_dev_id), getString(R.string.startapp_app_id));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tab);

    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
        (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle("");



    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivityTab.this, menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });



    StartAppAd.showSlider(this);
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivityTab.this);
    // Insert the Ad Unit ID
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Call displayInterstitial() function
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    HitGovtJobAdapter adapter = new HitGovtJobAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),HGJTitles,HGJNumboftabs);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        MainActivityTab.this.finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}



static class HitGovtJobAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


    CharSequence HGJTitles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
    int HGJNumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public HitGovtJobAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence hgjTitles[], int hgjTabNum) {
        super(fm);

        this.HGJTitles = hgjTitles;
        this.HGJNumbOfTabs = hgjTabNum;

    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
        {
            News_Recent newsRecent = new News_Recent();
            return newsRecent;
        }
        else             // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
        {
            News_Category newsCategory = new News_Category();
            return newsCategory;
        }

    }

    // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return HGJTitles[position];
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return HGJNumbOfTabs;
    }
}



public static class HitGovtJobFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAB_POSITION = "tab_position";

    public HitGovtJobFragment() {

    }

    public static HitGovtJobFragment newInstance(int tabPosition) {
        HitGovtJobFragment fragment = new HitGovtJobFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(TAB_POSITION, tabPosition);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refresh:
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_favorite:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), News_Favorite.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_about:
            Intent about = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About_Us.class);
            startActivity(about);
            return true;


        case R.id.menu_moreapp:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(getString(R.string.play_more_apps))));
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_rateapp:
            final String appName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appName)));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                startActivity(new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                                + appName)));
            }
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mAdView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mAdView.resume();
    startAppAd.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mAdView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}
```

}

But with above code toolbar not collapsed and viewpager scrolls freely. See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTxei.png).

And tablayout also not properly placed.

Any idea how can I fix this problem?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/r`enter code here`es/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`enter code here`
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabContentStart="72dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/tabLayout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center|left|start"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:borderWidth="0dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and than your activity
Note ItemFragment can be your fragment having list ItemFragment i am not enclosing this fragment:

```
package com.example.a61378.navigation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.a61378.navigation.dummy.DummyContent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,ItemFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    TabLayout mTabLayout;
    String tabPageTitles[] = {"Tab1", "Tab2"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        mTabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        FragmentManager fragment =getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentHomePagerAdapter fragmentHomePagerAdapter = new FragmentHomePagerAdapter(fragment, tabPageTitles.length);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(fragmentHomePagerAdapter);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListFragmentInteraction(DummyContent.DummyItem item) {

    }

    class FragmentHomePagerAdapter extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private int mTabCount;

        public FragmentHomePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
            super(fm);
            mTabCount = tabCount;
        }


        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            ItemFragment ViewGroceryfragment = ItemFragment.newInstance(10);
            return ViewGroceryfragment;// Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabPageTitles[position] ;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabCount;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Edit 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"

            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/hgj_nav"
                
 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"

                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#009688"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thankx for replying, but its Not working, app crash when I do this.

Comment: cleared some errors from the code, hope this works for you.

Comment: Please check question ill upload main java maybe now you help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nested scrollview to achieve this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/dark_orange"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"

            />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I have just did it in my project and its working like a boss :P

Comment: When I add nested scaollview viewpager not working everything hide.

Comment: why are you making all your views as child of drawer layout ?

Comment: i think you should keep you drawer in activity and the other layouts like collapsing toolbar, viewpager and tab in a fragment

Comment: Can you please explain how can I do this.

Comment: you are mixing all the things in a single layout let me find some tutorial for you

Comment: Can you please give me your email ?

Comment: could you explain a little bit about what you really want to do . What i understood so far is that you want a navigation view (side menu) and a layout having a collapsing tool bar and below that toolbar you want a viewpager

Comment: Mr baron i think its not allowed on stackoverflow

Comment: Yes I want same :) ,

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample [project](https://github.com/adeelturk/Collapsing-Tool-viewpager-and-tabs) which might help you in what you are looking for it has navigation view collapsing toolbar with viewpager and tabs over viewpager.